# How to add non-literal into a variable like jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frameworks

In JQuery at the last part of the code jQuery variable is assigned to a $ sign:

```js
// Expose jQuery and $ identifiers, even in
// AMD (#7102#comment:10, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/557)
// and CommonJS for browser emulators (#13566)
if ( typeof noGlobal === strundefined ) {
 window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
}
```

Now I'm making my own framework called ezo which promotes fast manipulation for DOM using id and program CSS through JavaScript file without making necessarily a CSS File and more code friendly.

I did the same as JQuery in ezo (with full democ code) :

```js
var ezo = function(selector) {
  var dom = document.getElementById(selector);

  dom.setText = function(string) {
    dom.innerText = string;
  };

  dom.appendText = function(string) {
    dom.innerText = dom.innerText + string;
  };

  dom.setSize = function(width, height) {
    $(selector).css("width", width);
    $(selector).css("height", height);
  };

  dom.setBGColor = function(color) {
    $(selector).css("background-color", color);
  };

  dom.setFontSize = function(size) {
    $(selector).css("font-size", size);
  }

  dom.setFontColor = function(color) {
    $(selector).css("color", color);
  }

  dom.align = function(al) {
    $(selector).css("text-align", al);
  };

  dom.getNodeName = function() {
    return $(selector)[0].nodeName;
  };

  return document.getElementById(selector);

};

$(document).ready = function() {

  window.ezo = window.# = ezo;

};
```

Then I tested my framework on a html file to manipulate nodes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ezo Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="ezo-1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="header"> This is a header! Edit Me </h1>
  <p id="par">I'm a lovely paragraph!</p>
  <div id="box">
    <p id="par2">I'm an empty div !</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

After I ran the html file the JS console warns me that # is an illegal token! How can I make # as a variable like ezo without having this error just like JQuery's $ sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make # as a variable like ezo without having this error just like JQuery's $ sign?

You can't. `#` isn't a valid [*IdentifierName* character](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6); `$` is. Variables and property name literals have to contain only valid *IdentifierName* characters. (There's slightly more to it, because the first character has additional requirements, but see the link for details.) There are basically only two non-letter characters you can use at the beginning of a variable or property name, `$` and `_`. Both have been used by Well Known Libraries. :-)

While you *could* create a window property using brackets notation and quotes:

```
window["#"] = ...
```

...that would obviously be really awkward to use, as you would have to write `window["#"]` everywhere (not just `#`). :-) Or of course, you could pick any letter of the English alphabet you like, really, and just warn people what it is, but that's probably not going to be popular. Or pick a non-English letter like Ω, but A) That might not be popular in Greece, and B) It's going to be awkward to type on most keyboards.

More realistic options:

- `ezo` is pretty short and easy to type, you could just use that.
- Or you could use `$` on the assumption that someone using your framework won't be using jQuery (or if they do, they can use jQuery's `noConflict`).
- Or `$$` (which was also used by PrototypeJS, but that's not widely used anymore except in legacy codebases)
- Or `_e`
- Or any of a million other things...

Comment: you can tell them even do something like $$ = ezo; so your symbol would be double $$

Comment: when I added window.ezo = ezo it was assigned but when I added window.e$ = ezo it said it is undefined?! why??

Comment: @NajiKadri: You'd have to show the code where you're doing that. If you mean the code at the end of your question, that's not how you use jQuery's `ready` and the function there never gets called. Fundamentally, `window.e$ = ezo;` will work. (FWIW, to *me*, `e$` is fairly awkward to type. These things are of course highly subjective.)

Comment: You can use both e$ and ezo because they are both defined as ezo object! so a developer can use any variable he wants!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript object names must begin with a Unicode Letter, or underscore _, dollar sign $. That's just how the language was defined. jQuery has colonized the $ and various libraries like underscore.js have prior claim to _. I would choose something with two characters or more, like $e or $z.

Comment: Does that means that JavaScript accept $ as a variable but don't accept # as a variable?? but they are both non-literal signs

Comment: @NajiKadri: Yes. The vast majority of programming languages allow letters and `_` as the first character of a variable name. JavaScript is unusual in that it also allows `$` there. But it (like most others) doesn't allow `#` in any part of a variable name.